# Get current screen resolution using .NET Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm using a .NET Core 3.1 console app in VS 2019. I'm trying to get current screen resolution (Windows display). I don't want to get monitor maximum resolution.

I have following batch code that works. I just want to check my resolution is 1024x768 or not.

Simply want to convert this code into true C# code without launching CMD by `Process.start`. I want to implement if else to check the resolution is 1024x768 or not.

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%# in  ('"wmic path Win32_VideoController  get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value"') do (
  set "%%#">nul
)

echo %CurrentHorizontalResolution%
echo %CurrentVerticalResolution%

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing `NuGet package System.Management`, you can access these parameters as explained [here](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/properties/currenthorizontalresolution.html):

```
    //  https://wutils.com/wmi/

    //  Install package System.Management (6.0.0)
    //  using System.Management;

    //create a management scope object
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");

    //create object query
    ObjectQuery query = 
        new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController " 
                      + "Where DeviceID=\"VideoController1\"");

    //create object searcher
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    //get a collection of WMI objects
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = 
        searcher.Get();

    //enumerate the collection.
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        // access properties of the WMI object
        Console.WriteLine("CurrentHorizontalResolution : {0}", 
            m["CurrentHorizontalResolution"]);
        Console.WriteLine("CurrentVerticalResolution : {0}", 
            m["CurrentVerticalResolution"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up on the answer from [Axel Kemper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537840/get-current-screen-resolution-using-net-core-console-application#answer-71538319), you can do this is in a one-liner

```cs
//get WMI object for VideoController1
var wmiMonitor = new ManagementObject("Win32_VideoController.DeviceID=\"VideoController1\"");
```

Then you can get the horizontal and vertical like this

```cs
var width = wmiMonitor["CurrentHorizontalResolution"];
var height = wmiMonitor["CurrentVerticalResolution"];
```

Remember to install the nuget package [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) before trying.